# Mule: how to send Array parameter to DB Update

Tags: mule

I have a PG table with a field of type char(10)[].

I need to update a record in the table with values from a Mule flow.

So, i did something like this:

```
flowVars.test=['aaa', 'bbb',ccc'];
```

Then, I'm trying to submit an update statement like this:

```
update tab1 set fld1=#[flowVars.test]
```

it's failing with the error:

```
Cannot cast an instance of java.util.ArrayList to type Types.ARRAY
```

My understanding is that SQL array should be used in this scenario but I can't figure out how to get an instance of such an array in a flow and how to work with it in MEL.

Can someone please advise?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found an answer in MuleSoft doc. 
Starting from version 3.6 DB connector supports custom types and allows defining mapping between SQL arrays and structures and custom user classes. 
It's documented [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/database-connector#user-defined-data-types) .

Comment: Did it take about a month to research this? No offense meant, just surprised to see how much it takes to research things in mule

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources that suggest to use the `Connection#createArrayOf()`. But I don't know how to use it in the *Database* connector.

However, for this purpose I will do this solution:

1. Convert the ArrayList to a String. It should be formed as: `{value1, value2, ...}`
2. Change the Database Query Type from **Parameterized** into **Dynamic**
3. Update the SQL Query become: `update tab1 set fld1 = '#[flowVars.test]'`. The additional single quote is required for this query type.

Finally, by using the following configuration I can update field of type *character(10)[]*:

```
<expression-transformer expression="#[flowVars.test = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'].toString().replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')]" doc:name="Expression"/>
<db:update config-ref="Postgre_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[update tab1 set fld1 = '#[flowVars.test]']]></db:dynamic-query>
</db:update>
```